# Ошибка PHP yntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Tags: php

```
<?php $res_div ="<div class='".$rep."' value='".basename($this->PATH)."/".basename($files)."'>".basename($this->PATH)."/".basename($files)."</div>"; ?>
```

PHP yntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW фот такую ошибку выдает, вроде все кавычки закрыты, помогите

Comment:     T_DOUBLE_ARROW  =>  array syntax

[Отсюда][1]


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

Comment: Хмм, у меня всё работает. Вероятно ошибка до этого кода, на предидущей строке возможно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW - двойная стрелка (=>) используется не там, где надо.
Ищите и исправляйте или скиньте весь блок кода