# Почему не работает ajax вызов

Tags: php, ajax

На стороне клиента:

```
function generate()
{

    var str = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://generator:91',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            result = JSON.parse(data);
            $newWord = result.str;
        }
    });    
    return str
}
```

На стороне сервера:

```
echo json_encode([$newWord] => "str", JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

браузер выдает:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in I:\home\generator\www\index.php on line 163
```

Comment: [$newWord] => "str" - php скорее всего не знает что это...(да и я не особо понял что делает такая запись)

Comment: я бы понял еще  ["str"=>$newWord]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/224709/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-php-yntax-error-unexpected-t-double-arrow

Comment: А разве не массив надо возвращать?

Comment: нет, нужна переменная